Is the mapping space from $\Delta[k]$ to a simplicial set $X$ weak equivalent to $X$?
Let $X$ be a simplicial set. It is well known that a model for the path object can be given by the mapping space $\mathrm{Hom}(\Delta[1], X)$. In particular this offers a fiber replacement for the diagonal map $X \to X \times X$ by taking the composition
$$ X \overset{\sim}{\to} \mathrm{Hom}(\Delta[1], X) \twoheadrightarrow X \times X $$
Where the first map sends each simplex in $X$ to the constant homotopy at that simplex and it is a weak equivalence.
Is $X \to \mathrm{Hom}(\Delta[k], X)$ a model for a higher path object? That is,

Is it true that the map $X \to \mathrm{Hom}(\Delta[k], X)$ sending each simplex in $X$ to the constant $k$-homotopy at that simplex is a weak equivalence? If so, does it additionally admit a homotopy inverse?

Does this provide a fiber replacement for the higher diagonal $X \to X^{k+1}$?


I am mainly interested in an answer to 1, as 2 would likely follow immediately.


Yes, because $\Delta[k]$ is contractible.
Yes, at least if $X$ is a Kan complex, because the inclusion of vertices in $\Delta[k]$ is a cofibration.


@FernandoMuro I suspected this must be the reason but I don't see how to use the fact that $\Delta[k]$ is contractible to prove this. Do you know of a reference?

The map $\Delta[k]\rightarrow *$ is a homotopy equivalence.
